# Function powershell

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, microsoft-teams, call-queue

So I created a function that assigns licenses to users. When I execute the function it shows me an error.

```
Function Create_resource_account ($UserPrincipalName, $ApplicationId, $DisplayName) {
try {
    New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -DisplayName $DisplayName
}    
catch {
    write-Log(“Error while creating a new application instance for a Call queue with $UserPrincipalName”)
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Write-Log($ErrorMessage)
    Write-Log($FailedItem)
    # exit(0)
}
}

Function AddLicense {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string] $UserPrincipalName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [string] $License,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
    [string] $UsageLocation
)
process {
    $LicensedUser = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licenses.AccountSkuId
    if ( $LicensedUser -eq $License) {
        Write-Output ("No licence to assign for $UserPrincipalName")
    }
    else {
        try {
            Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -UsageLocation $UsageLocation 
            Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses $License
        }
        catch {
            write-Log(“Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to $UserPrincipalName”)
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
            Write-Log($ErrorMessage)
            Write-Log($FailedItem)
            exit(0)
        }
    }
}
}
$Util2 = Get-PnPListItem -List "2"
foreach ($temp2 in $Util2) {

        $CQNom = $temp2['CQ_nom']
        $CQMail = $temp2['CQ_Compte_de_ressource']
        $CQNum = $temp2['Tel_sda']    
  

    #Création des ressources
    $newCqRa = Create_resource_account $CQMail 11cd3e2e-fccb-42ad-ad00-878b93575e07 "RA_$CQNom"   #Call queue


    #Assign licence
    $User = Get-AzureADUser -objectid $newCqRa.ObjectId | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
    AddLicense $User "domain:PHONESYSTEM_VIRTUALUSER" "US"}
```

the error

```
get-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: CQ-JeanPierreViseur@domain.onmicrosoft.com.
Au caractère Ligne:31 : 22
+ ... nsedUser = (get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licen ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetUser
```

It shows me the same error for all users. I told myself that there is a problem in my function Addlicense. Someone can help me please

I store what my program does in a logging file and this is what it writes to me:
"Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to CQ-EricDesbordes@domain.onmicrosoft.com
The parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to CQ-JeanPierreViseur@domain.onmicrosoft.com
The parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

Comment: It'd help to know exactly what you're passing into the function you created.  It looks like you're appending 'cq-' to the name.  Is that the actual UPN in the system?  Validate the UPN assigned to the identity object and ensure you're referencing them correctly.  Also, there's a formatting structure for powershell that would make your code easier to read:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: @Colyn1337 - I store what my program does in a logging file and this is what it writes to me: "Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to CQ-EricDesbordes@domain.onmicrosoft.com
The parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to CQ-JeanPierreViseur@domain.onmicrosoft.com
The parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried this at our end and we were able to get users and assign licenses as well. One quick thing to consider is that the command [Set-MsolUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0) should be used only to update basic properties. To update the user license please use [Set-MsolUserLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserlicense?view=azureadps-1.0).

```
 Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName User1@contoso.com -AddLicenses domain:MCOPSTN_5
```